# Constrained object teleports after influence becomes 0

Tags: animation, constraints

I'm currently trying to animate a character pulling out a gun and came across a problem with my "Child Of" constraints. The gun is constrained to the character's thigh and at the part when he should pull out the gun, I switched the thigh constraint off and then turned on the hand constraint. What happened is that the gun teleported to its original transform from the first frame. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

---

[image]

**The frame where the hand constraint influence is keyed to 1**

---

[image]

**The frame where the hand constraint is keyed to 1 and thigh constraint to 0**

Comment: to switch from a parent to another, the Dynamic Parent addon by Roman Volodin is very convenient as it automatize everything: https://github.com/romanvolodin/dynamic_parent

Comment: Check out https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/210021/how-to-unattach-an-object-and-reattach-it-somewhere-else-in-an-animation